# Regex to find multiple \n and replace with only one <br/>

Tags: java, regex

I've got a regex `.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "< br />"));` which replaces all `\n` and replaces with `< br/>`.

The thing I wanted here, is to replace more than one `\n` in a row by only one `< br/>`
What would be a regex for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the `+` quantifier, which means "one or more":

```
.replaceAll("(\r?\n)+", "<br />"));
```